# How to sign in users to a subdomain and make the session available on another subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies, session-cookies

Is it possible to set a session cookie on login.app.com, and have the session cookie available on foo.app.com?

I want to have a central login location: login.app.com. Once user Cayote logs in at login.app.com, I want to transport him to his page on its own subdomain: acme.app.com. Once he gets there, he should be logged in.

I'm not sure how to bridge the gap between login.app.com and acme.app.com.

I'm using Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You just have to declare your cookie for all your subdomains:

```
# config/initializers/session_store.rb
Testapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_testapp_session', :domain => :all
```

By declaring domain => :all, the cookie for login.app.com and acme.app.com will be set with the domain .app.com so the session will be shared between the subdomains.

Comment: is possible to take this idea a step further and make it that  you login from `login.app.com` and get transported to `sailor.app.com` (as with my question), but when you go to `pilot.app.com` your session would not carry over? Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Mohamad, you'd have to set the name of the session cookie key to something different for the app on pilot.app.com if you wanted to do that, which is certainly possible. Sessions are cookie-based, so it just comes down to making sure the cookie is there for each domain.